# Why increase in resistance of register used in circuit show lesser average power dissipation

Tags: power-supply, power, transistors, digital-logic, resistors

I am working on 6 transistor full adder circuit.

[image: Schematic]

Red marked resistors (25k) are used to show all pattern of full adder correctly. But it show wired behavior. When I increase resistance from 25k to 50k there is minor change in waveform but average power dissipation of circuit decrease. But theory say more is resistance of circuit more power dissipation.

I am using 5.0 V voltage supply and use Tanner EDA for circuit simulation at 180 nm technology.

Comment: The theory *I* would use is \$P=\dfrac{V^2}{R}\$

Comment: Also, 180nm technologies probably aren't designed for a 5.0V supply unless you're using something that probably isn't L=180nm. (Which wouldn't make sense for something like an adder)

Answer (score 2):

Ohms law can be shown to imply higher resistances produce more power when the supply to them is constant current - clearly as resistance increases, the voltage across the resistor increases thus power also increases because power = voltage * current.

However, on your circuit you have a constant voltage supply so current reduces as resistance increases and this means power decreases by 50% as resistance doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Power consumption = static + dynamic power. 
By increasing the resistance, you are sacrificing speed for power consumption.

The internal capacitance of the mosfets can't be brought to the correct voltage (charged) in the same amount of time (as previously with the lower resistance) due there being less current. So the circuit will be slower and use less power.